# Hibernate cascade delete multiple levels

Tags: hibernate, cascading-deletes

Sorry for may English. I have 4 tables:

```
**t1**
id

**t2**
id
t1_id

**t3**
id
t2_id

**t4**
id
t1_id
t2_id
```

In t2 entity I use it:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="t2")
Set<t3> t3Set;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="t2")
Set<t4> t4Set;
```

If i delete t2 entity, then t3-4 also to be deleted. But it is not working with multiple levels. How to delete t1?

Comment: it is deleting value from t3 not from t4 right ?

Comment: No. If I delete `t1`, then should be deleted `t4, t3, t2`. I can to add `t1_id` in `t3`. But how can i to set the sequence of removal.

Comment: from table t4 remove t1 and t2 and add t3 it will work

Comment: You did not understand me. I want to delete a row from `t1`. But it is not working as with `t2`. Need to record from the tables were removed in sequence. The sequence of removal t1: t4-t3-t2-t1.